# Cache Coherency with Tarantool

Tags: tarantool

- I understand that Tarantool has ACID transactions within a stored procedure. My question is: does it also make sure in-memory data is in sync with persistent file system data? For Example, if I change 5 records using a Stored Proc and something goes wrong while writing the changes to WAL file, will the in-memory cache roll back to original values for ALL 5 records?
- Also, while an update transaction is in progress, will other readers see 'dirty' uncommitted records or a consistent view of the records as these existed before transaction started?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Tarantool has a special function for transaction control[1] inside stored procedure. But it has some limitations for instance: you can't call fiber.yield()[2] (that includes underlying calls, i.e. fio, sockets and so on) inside box.begin() box.end() section. You can find more about transaction control here: https://tarantool.io/en/doc/1.9/book/box/atomic.html?highlight=yield.

And also, tarantool supports fsync[3].

[1] https://tarantool.io/en/doc/1.9/book/box/box_txn_management.html?highlight=commit#lua-function.box.commit

[2] https://tarantool.io/en/doc/1.9/reference/reference_lua/fiber.html?highlight=yield#lua-function.fiber.yield

[3] https://tarantool.io/en/doc/1.9/reference/configuration/index.html?highlight=fsync#confval-wal_mode

2. It is possible only if a user uses fibers and don't control own codes. That means that is possible only if a logical error exists inside user's codes.

You are welcome.